# On iOS using SnapKit, why is the origin point of a subview not the origin point of its superview?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uikit, snapkit

Generally, when you think of a superview-subview relationship, one would tend to expect that the origin point of a subview would be contained by the superview (typically being the origin point of the superview). In `UIKit` on iOS, however, that does not seem to be the case. Why does a subview's origin point (0,0) of the `UIWindow`?

To demonstrate, the following code produces two UIViews, one being a subview of the other. For some reason, `innerView` origin point appears to be (0,0) of the entire `UIWindow`. I would expect the origin point of `innerView` to be the origin point of `outerView` (whose origin point is dictated by the center point of its superview).

**What I get:**

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

let superView = self.view!
superView.backgroundColor = .white

let outerView = UIView()
outerView.backgroundColor = .cyan
superView.addSubview(outerView)

outerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.width.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
    make.height.equalTo(superView.snp.height).dividedBy(3)
    make.center.equalToSuperview()
 }

let innerView = UIView()
innerView.backgroundColor = .purple
outerView.addSubview(innerView)
innerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.height.width.equalToSuperview().dividedBy(2)
}
```

[image: Actual]

**What I want:**

Adding an additional `SnapKit` constraint line sets the `innerView` origin point to the origin point of `outerView` but I find this step to be extraneous.

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

let superView = self.view!
superView.backgroundColor = .white

let outerView = UIView()
outerView.backgroundColor = .cyan
superView.addSubview(outerView)

outerView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.width.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
    make.height.equalTo(superView.snp.height).dividedBy(3)
    make.center.equalToSuperview()
 }

let innerView = UIView()
innerView.backgroundColor = .purple
outerView.addSubview(innerView)
innerView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.left.equalToSuperview() // Set origins equal
    make.height.width.equalToSuperview().dividedBy(2)
}
```

[image: Expected]

This is likely a fundamental misunderstanding of the view hierarchy in iOS as I have relied on Storyboards until now. This is my first foray into programmatic UI on iOS, so I am still wrapping my head around all the nuances. Right now, the evidence leads me to believe that every single view -- no matter where it exists in the view hierarchy -- starts at position (0,0) of the key `UIWindow`.

Comment: Please ignore the fact that I am not using `equalToSuperview()` in some instances where it would make more sense. That was for my testing purposes and I forgot to revert back.

Answer (score 1):

Inside every view is a new coordinate space. The window does not determine the origin of subviews without an origin. The most interesting thing about your example is that you do not give your purple view a frame and thus no origin. If you were to print the origin of the purple it would be the negative of half the height and width of the purple as the origin in relation to the superview.  The main thing is to give it an origin via autolayout or assigning a point. I guess we are lucky to even have an origin established. Here is an example of adding views in the coordinate system with a screenshot description.

```
import UIKit

class MeasureViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //view will start at 0,0 of superview which is the main view and be the same size

        let green = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))
        green.backgroundColor = .green
        self.view.addSubview(green)

        //first inside view  half of outers width and height
        let blue = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: green.bounds.midX, height: green.bounds.midY))
        blue.backgroundColor = .blue
        // in this case it is self.view.center and outer.center but won't always be just works because coordinate space matches
        blue.center = green.center
        green.addSubview(blue)

        let white = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: blue.bounds.midX, height: blue.bounds.midY))
        //will not be in the center of firstInside because it is using the coordinate derived from outer
        white.center = blue.center
        white.backgroundColor = .white
        blue.addSubview(white)

        let redDot = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10))
        redDot.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        redDot.backgroundColor = .red
        //will be the center of blue center because it is half the width and height and be correct
        redDot.center = CGPoint(x: blue.bounds.midX, y: blue.bounds.midY)
        blue.addSubview(redDot)

        //same size as white view above but no origin.  this is bad
        let noOriginView = UIView()
        noOriginView.backgroundColor = .cyan
        noOriginView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: blue.bounds.midX, height: blue.bounds.midY)

        blue.addSubview(noOriginView)
        print("Test withoutFrame \(noOriginView.frame.origin)")
    }

}
```

Description and screenshot
[image: screenshot]

These fundamentals are true of manual layout, autolayout, and Snapkit. With autolayout and Snapkit you would not directly set the points and bounds but there needs to be constraints that do the same thing.

With Autolayout:
After much testing with Autolayout I do think if a view is missing position constraints it is converted to 0,0 of the window which means the actual origin would be negative values for x,y with the examples above adjusting to have a converted origin to window coordinate space.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I knew that it had to be something simple that I was missing. I did notice the oddities in the frame and bound properties but wasn’t sure what meaning it had. So, a follow up question, why does `addSubview` not inherently set the child’s frame to the parent’s? That would seem logical to me, but there must be a reason for that to not be the case? Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: So, another follow up. I expected that if I were to use `let innerView = UIView(frame: outerView.frame` that `innerView` origin point would equal `outerView` origin point -- like what I want to happen. However, that still didn't happen. Am I still missing something? In your example, you dealt mostly with centers. I don't want to center my views; I want my `innerView` to start at the top-left-most position (i.e. origin) of my `outerView`

Comment: If you used let innerView = UIView(frame: outerView.bounds) you will get the same origin point. Using frame you get the origin coordinate of the outerView which could be a non 0,0 origin.  Suppose the outer view had an origin of 50,50 then the innerView would have an origin of 50,50 of the outerView which would not be 0,0

Comment: The latter example is the result that I want. I want `innerView` to be a proper child of `outerView` -- existing only within the area of `outerView`. If `outerView` origin is `(50, 50)`, I want `innerView` to also originate from `(50, 50)`. Unfortunately, I am still not seeing that behavior when I use `UIView(frame: outerView.frame`. I also don't see the expected behavior when using `UIView(frame: outerView.bounds`. It may have been unclear in the question, but the second image is the result that I want -- but I don't want to have to manually set the Top and Left constraints manually.

Comment: Doing some experiments with just plain `UIView` without using AutoLayout and SnapKit, the views behave exactly like I would expect them to. My problem exists somewhere in my AutoLayout constraints.

Comment: @NickAlexander are you adding them all to the main view or adding as a subview because the coordinate system is different depending on where you are adding. It gets reset for each time into a child view.

Comment: Yes, the way the coordinates are reset makes perfect sense and is exactly what I would expect to happen. If `outerView` originates at (50,50) of the super view and `innerView` is a subview of `outerView` then `innerView` origin is (0,0) which will be the top-left corner of `outerView`. For some reason, though, that was not the behavior observed after applying my AutoLayout constraints.

I am adding `outerView` as a subview of `self.view` and I am adding `innerView` as a subview of `outerView`, both by calling `addSubview`.

Comment: I want `innerView` to originate at the top left hand corner of `outerView`, or (0,0). If `innerView` is a subview of `outerView`, shouldn't that be the case by default?

Comment: This is the result: http://imgur.com/B75yJEK
Is this happening because AutoLayout doesn't have constraints for the position of the view? I still wouldn't expect the view to be positioned outside of it's superview.

Comment: Might be that Snapkit translates the window 0,0 and autoassigns it. Let me check. Never used it

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior if I use manual AutoLayout constraints instead of SnapKit. I am guessing that AutoLayout is just panicking because it does not have a position constraint and automatically positions it at (0,0) of the ViewController's root view. I suppose I just have to set the top and left margins equal to the superview on every nested subview like in the origin example.

Comment: @NickAlexander maybe autolayout translates the view into the windows coordinates. I need better internet than a phone to check.

Comment: It appears my comment just above is correct and you are on to something with your question. After much testing with Autolayout I am nearly positive that if a view is missing position constraints it is converted to 0,0 of the window which means in our example the actual origin would be a negative x,y to adjust to this conversion to the window coordinate space. I updated the bottom of my answer to state this. I have never left off position constraints so I have not stumbled on to this. Good luck